# regex to initialize given name

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of names such as

```
lastname1, Abc-Def
lastname2, Abc
```

I am trying to find a regex to initialize the given names (that come after the comma `,`) so it gives me:

```
lastname1, A.-D.
lastname2, A.
```

The closest I got: https://regex101.com/r/nKtPCq/2/

```
(.*), ([A-zÀ-ú])\w*-?([A-zÀ-ú])+
```

Comment: you can't do that, as you can't pass a condition to add the last dot to the result... the closest you can get is https://regex101.com/r/nKtPCq/3, you need to add some condition in the programming language you are using, to add the last dot

Comment: I am using the R language.

Comment: Generally it would be better to just split that string and get what you want.

Comment: You may use this: https://regex101.com/r/nKtPCq/4

Comment: Similar to @anubhava's suggestion: `([^,\n]+, |(?!^)\G[^\pL'\n])([\pL])[\pL']+` which works for any unicode letters and also allows `'` character (although I'm unsure if `D'Andre` should be `D.'A.` or `D.A.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, instead of regex you could also do this if you want:

```r
str1 = "lastname1, Abc-Def"
str2 = "lastname2, Abc"

initialize = function(nameString) {
  namesList = strsplit(nameString, ", ")
  splitLast = strsplit(namesList[[1]][2], "-")
  initials = paste(substr(splitLast[[1]], 1, 1), ".", sep="", collapse="-")
  paste(namesList[[1]][1], ", ", initials, sep="")
}

print(initialize(str1)) # "lastname1, A.-D."
print(initialize(str2)) # "lastname2, A."
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/AlienatedAdorableKeyboard#main.r)